# Array not in array for doctrine query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.8

I need to use a condition like array is not in array. I have array which one has two element for search. For example

**(3,1) NOT IN ((2,3),(1,3),(1,32))**

it's work as SQL query in phpmyadmin. But not worked as doctrine query.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 

$qb = $em->getRepository('FangoUserBundle:User')
        ->createQueryBuilder('user')  
        ->leftJoin('user.collabInvitationTarget', 'invite')
        ->where('(:currentUserId, user.id) NOT IN (:inviteArr)')
        ->setParameter('currentUserId', $this->getUser()->getId())
        ->setParameter('inviteArr', $invites, \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY);
```

*An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("[Syntax Error] line 0, col 304: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ','") in FangoCollabaignBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 54.*

Any advice ?

Comment: I think the problem comes from your WHERE.
What are you expecting from this condition exactly ?

Comment: `(array) [currentUserId, user.id]` should not in `(array) [:inviteArr]`

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the final answer, but there are a few things to correct here.

1. While it's tolerated in basic SQL, query should be between double quotes, and string should be between simple quotes. Not the opposite.
2. From your code, I'm guessing that your custom query is in the controller. It would be best to move it into the entity repository, withing a new function, and then call this function in your controller.
   It's odd that you don't get an error for `createQueryBuilder()` as it doesn't exists in this context.
3. Avoid alias that could be mistaken for entity names.
4. Your query is wrong around the `where()` I think.

Taking in account that you applied point 2, this is how I would try to do it.

```
public function getNameYourFunction($user, $invites) {
    $em=$this->getEntityManager();
    $qb=$em->createQueryBuilder()

    $qb->select("u")
       ->from(User::class, "u")
       ->leftJoin("u.collabInvitationTarget", "i")
       ->where($qb->expr()->notin("u.id", "(:inviteArrA)"))
       ->andWhere($qb->expr()->notin(":currentUserId", "(:inviteArrB)"))
       ->setParameters(array(
           'currentUserId'=>$user->getId(),
           'inviteArrA'=>implode(',', $invites),
           'inviteArrB'=>implode(',', $invites),
       ));
}
```

You will notice that I'm using `User::class`.
Make sure to import it in your repository by adding this line :
`use FangoUserBundle\Entity\User;` (may be different `use`in your case)

This is what I would do based on your code.
Tell us if it solved your problem.

Comment: No it's not a true solution but thank you for time and you give to me an  idea. I made a trick for search array and haystack array. I concat the element with underscore like 3_2 and (3_1, 4_2) and looking for only one element. It's works for now.